# Apache Solr Spelling check does not work with a sentence

Tags: php, apache, solr, solr-schema

Spelling correction work with incorrect words in search box like,

```
"contempory","singar","dancar", etc.
```

for that it gives correct spellings like,

```
"contemporary","singer","dancer", etc.
```

But when I search,

```
"contempory singer"
```

It gives results for correct word "singer" and does not gives spelling suggestions for "contempory".

But when both the words are incorrect like,

```
"contempory singar"
```

it gives results.

what to do for sentence correction which have a single incorrect word ??

I am pasting my "/select" request handler here

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
 <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="wt">json</str>
    <int name="rows">10</int>
    <str name="defType">edismax</str>
    <str name="qf">attributes^50 talent_name_1^60 talent_name_2^20 nofyears^60 living_city_name^30 specialization_name^60 specification_name^60</str>
    <str name="tie">0.1</str>
    <str name="sort">score desc, createdate desc</str>
    <!-- Solr will use suggestions from both the 'default' spellchecker
         and from the 'wordbreak' spellchecker and combine them.
         collations (re-written queries) can include a combination of
         corrections from both spellcheckers -->

    <!-- Spellcheckers defaults -->
    <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">wordbreak</str>
    <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">0</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">1</str>

    <!-- Faceting defaults -->
    <str name="facet">on</str>
    <str name="facet.sort">index</str>        
    <str name="facet.field">talent_name</str>
    <str name="facet.field">living_city_name</str>
    <str name="facet.field">fresherorexperience</str>
    <str name="facet.field">talent_exp</str>
    <str name="facet.field">talent_exp_hash</str>
    <str name="facet.field">talent_type_1</str>
    <str name="facet.field">talent_type_2</str>

    <str name="facet.field">skin_color</str>
    <str name="facet.field">skin_type</str>
    <str name="facet.field">weight</str>
    <str name="facet.field">wrinkles_on</str>
    <str name="facet.field">hair_color</str>
    <str name="facet.field">hair_type</str>
    <str name="facet.field">hair_length</str>
    <str name="facet.field">height_feet_underscore</str>
    <str name="facet.field">physique</str>
    <str name="facet.field">eye_color</str>
    <str name="facet.field">eye_shape</str>
    <str name="facet.field">ear_types</str>
    <str name="facet.field">nose_type</str>
    <str name="facet.field">lips_type</str>
    <str name="facet.field">cheek_shape</str>

    <str name="facet.pivot">talent_id_1,specialization_name_1_underscore</str>
    <str name="facet.pivot">talent_id_2,specialization_name_2_underscore</str>
    <str name="facet.pivot">talent_id_3,specialization_name_3_underscore</str>
    <str name="facet.pivot">talent_id_4,specialization_name_4_underscore</str>
    <str name="facet.pivot">talent_id_5,specialization_name_5_underscore</str>
    <str name="facet.pivot">talent_id_6,specialization_name_6_underscore</str>
    <str name="facet.pivot">talent_id_7,specialization_name_7_underscore</str>
    <str name="facet.pivot">talent_id_8,specialization_name_8_underscore</str>
    <str name="facet.field">gender</str>
    <str name="facet.range.other">after</str>
    <str name="facet.range">age</str>
    <int name="f.age.facet.range.start">0</int>
    <int name="f.age.facet.range.end">90</int>
    <int name="f.age.facet.range.gap">15</int>
  </lst>
  <arr name="last-components">
    <str>spellcheck</str>
  </arr>

 </requestHandler>
```

Thank you

Comment: do you use quotes around multiple words during search? Is it a phrase query?

Comment: No. I am not using quotes. Query will be `contempory singar`